# Accessor must declare a body because 'property' is not marked as abstract or extern

Tags: c#

I've got this enum at the top of my instance class:

```
    public Enum RecommendationPage
    {
        Search,
        Cart
    }
```

I'm using it in static methods or at least attempting to.  I get the error "Accessor must declare a body because 'property' is not marked as abstract or extern".  This code is in a handler .ashx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make [`enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28VS.80%29.aspx) lowercase.  You're telling the compiler that this is a property returning a [`System.Enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx), but you haven't specified the `get` or `set` part of the property.

Comment: I don't think there are any C# *keywords* that start with a capital -- that might help to keep in mind to prevent this kind of mistake in the future.

Answer (score 3):

First "Enum" has to be a small keyword "enum", it is assuming this declaration as property declaration instead of enum.